# Can I use eye hooks in a cement retaining wall for my garden project? (Support climbing rose bushes against a cement wall.)

Tags: hardware, cement, gardening

Here is a pic of the wall in question. Don't worry about the cracks. I already filled it in and am going to do the stairs when the weather gets drier outside. If you see the strip of soil that separates the retaining wall from the sidewalk that is where I want to plant climbing rose bushes. Due to limited space and for a simpler, cleaner appearance I was thinking of drilling some holes and then using rubber/plastic anchors to screw in some eye hooks. This was my idea instead of putting trellises in the ground. Then as the canes of the climbing rose bush grow I will use garden ties to bring them closer to the wall by tying them to the eye hooks.

Here is a pic of the area in question:
[image]

My plans are as follow:

1. Repair cracks and broken stairs.
2. Apply a textured concrete coating to the entire facade to improve appearance.
3. Water-seal it to protect it.
4. Install a few eye hooks with appropriate anchors that aren't too big to support climbing rosebushes.

Also, to minimize the appearance of the eye hooks can I paint over them with the textured concrete coating so that the metal isn't visible? If not, can anyone recommend a suitable substitute? I've never used a textured concrete coating before but it appears that you just paint it on with a roller or a brush. I hope this makes our retaining wall look a lot better. That's an important part of my overall goal with this project.

Basically the look I'm going for is a climbing rosebush that looks like it's "hugging" the wall. This is the rosebush I am buying:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could get a cleaner look by drilling the holes, inserting the plugs, bending  lengths of your wire in half, insert the U-end of the wire into the plug, then drive a screw into the plug, and not use screw-eyes.

Comment: +1, that's a novel idea. P.S. use stainless steel wire.

Comment: I'm not sure if metal rubbing up against the canes is a good idea. The garden wire that is sold at garden supply centers is usually coated with a plastic or rubber so that it doesn't gnaw away at where it's holding the plant up.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can, assuming the surface of the concrete isn't disintegrating. I am a bit concerned about that given the state of the stairs and the way that crack on the face is abscessing. You'll know when you try.

I'd use a rotary hammer to slowly and carefully drill a grid of 3/8" holes for plastic plugs. Use high bit speed and light pressure, drilling about 1/2" deeper than the plugs' length. Insert the plugs, then do your coating. Twist in galvanized eyes only when they're needed. This will keep the wall above the roses looking cleaner while the rose plants are smaller.

Galvanized metal will have a coordinating appearance and won't look crudded up with paint like they would if you applied the coating over them. You could also use stainless for a higher-quality corrosion resistance. They could be spray painted to conceal them.

My daughter is named Adrien, by the way. She'd adore your roses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This pic is a bit old but after taking this photo I used some the latex adhesive that was in the cement and mortar department (it looks like watered down milk) and applied it to the area after I cleaned it well. Then I mixed the same adhesive with some mortar and went in to do some patchwork. It's not done as I need to get the right tool to make it look smooth and complete. But I applied this mixture to the deep cracks to see if I could save it. Two years later it's completely solid and is not cracking or budging in any way.